# How to use chai json schema with es6 syntax

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai, jsonschema

I'm working in a project which uses es6 syntax, for example, instead of require it uses import. In this particular case for importing chai json schema I use the following line:

```
import jsonSchema from 'chai-json-schema';
```

But I can't figure out how to tell chai to use json schema using es6 syntax.

In the [project documentation](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-json-schema) shows how to have chai use chai json schema like this:

```
var chai = require('chai');
chai.use(require('chai-json-schema'));
```

How can I do this with es6 syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the line to perform the import first and then call `chai.use`. This works:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import jsonSchema from 'chai-json-schema';
chai.use(jsonSchema);
```

If you want to import individual bits of `chai` together with `chai` itself, you can do:

```
import chai, { expect, should } from 'chai';
import jsonSchema from 'chai-json-schema';
chai.use(jsonSchema);
```